# sqlite statement not ok... why? - iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select

I've been working on incorporating a sqlite db in my iPhone app. The database has been created, and I have successfully inserted elements into the database. Now, when I try to select from the db, my prepare statement is not meeting the requirement of SQLITE_OK. Here is the code where I create the database:

```
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXPENSES (id integer primary key autoincrement, unix_date integer, date_time text, purpose text, start_mile text, end_mile text, distance text, fees text, party_id integer)";
```

and here is the code I am using to extract the data:

```
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
printf("in getExpense\n");
//expenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM EXPENSES"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        printf("right before the while loop\n");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            printf("in the while loop\n");
            VehicleExpense *expense = [[VehicleExpense alloc] init];

            NSInteger *newTimeStamp = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

            NSString *newDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

            NSString *newPurpose = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            NSString *newStart = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            NSString *newEnd = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
            NSString *newDistance = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
            NSString *newFees = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];
            NSInteger *newPartyId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 8);

            expense.unix_date = newTimeStamp;
            expense.date = newDate;
            expense.purpose = newPurpose;
            expense.start_mile = newStart;
            expense.end_mile = newEnd;
            expense.distance = newDistance;
            expense.fees = newFees;
            expense.party_id = newPartyId;

            [expenses addObject: expense];
            printf("expense add");

            [newDate release];
            [newPurpose release];
            [newStart release];
            [newEnd release];
            [newDistance release];
            [newFees release];

            [expense release];

            expense_count++;

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }else{
        printf("the prepare statement is not ok\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
}else{
    printf("couldn't open the db\n");
}
```

The second if-statement keeps failing for some reason?

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `NSLog(@"ERROR: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(expeseDB));` to print the error to the console (in your else statements). The error usually says exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("the prepare statement is not ok\n");` is not really helpful at all. Try something like

```
NSLog(@"prepare failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(expenseDB));
```

Comment: It just started working...I didn't change any code?... well thanks-I didn't know how to get the error message.

Comment: should use %s instead of %@, since it's a `C string`

Comment: Ok...I will...thanks-I'm obviously pretty new to obj-c. I've been doing java.